# Deletion-contraction versus addition-identification

Tags: graph-theory

Short version: there are two common formulas for computing the chromatic polynomial of a graph. They go by the names, deletion-contraction and addition-identification. They are equivalent, mathematically, but differ in their application. I know graphs for which a-i is more efficient than d-c. Are there graphs for which d-c is more efficient than a-i?

Long version: Let $G$ be a graph. The chromatic polynomial $P(G,k)$ gives the number of ways to color the vertices of $G$, if $k$ colors are available, and no two adjacent vertices get the same color. If $G$ is chordal (that is, if every cycle in $G$ has a chord, a pair of vertices adjacent in $G$ but not adjacent in the cycle), then you can compute $P(G,k)$ by "following your nose". If $G$ is not chordal, then you can use either of these formulas, repeatedly if necessary, to reduce to the case of chordal graphs: $$P(G,k)=P(G-e,k)-P(G/e,k)\tag1$$ $$P(G,k)=P(G+e,k)+P(G/e,k)\tag2$$ (1) is called "deletion-contraction"; $e$ is an arbitrary edge of $G$, $G-e$ is what's left when you delete $e$ from $G$, and $G/e$ is what results when you contract $e$ to a point. (2) is called "addition-identification"; $e$ is an edge not in $G$, $G+e$ is the result of adding $e$ to $G$, and $G/e$ is what happens when you identify the endpoints of $e$. (1) and (2) are mathematically equivalent, but differ in the way they are applied, as (1) deletes an edge from $G$, while (2) adds an edge to $G$.

I know examples where (2) is more efficient than (1). E.g., if $G$ is $K_{2,3}$ (each of two vertices $A,B$ joined to each of three vertices $X,Y,Z$), then any edge-deletion yields a non-chordal graph, so a second application of (1) is called for, but if $e$ in (2) joins $A$ and $B$ then $G+e$ and $G/e$ are both chordal and no further reduction is needed.

I know many examples where (1) and (2) are equally efficient (e.g., if $G$ is a 4-cycle). I don't know any example where (1) is strictly more efficient than (2) (and occasionally I think I can prove this can't happen). Is there a graph that requires fewer iterations of (1) than of (2)?

Comment: I would use (1) to derive the formula for $P(C_n,k)$ and I never thought about doing it another way. How does it work out using (2)?

Comment: @bof, I take it that by $C_n$ you mean an $n$-cycle. If you let $e$ be an edge joining two vertices that are "adjacent-but-one", then using (2) you get $P(C_n,k)=(k-2)P(C_{n-1},k)+(k-1)P(C_{n-2},k)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Some students and I developed a theorem related to these recurrences that you will probably be interested in. We're taking the summer to get our thoughts in order, but I'll be happy to share with you after that time. I'm just leaving a little note here so that one or the other of us will remember to revisit it in August, perhaps.

Comment: @AustinMohr it's past august

Comment: And I'm still interested, @Austin.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Since the work isn't really an answer to this question, I could email their partial results to you personally. You can find my website (and thus contact info) on my profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where deletion-contraction is more efficient:

Start with a clique with four vertices. Add a vertex A connected to two vertices of the clique and a vertex B connected to the other two. Connect A and B.

Deleting and contracting the edge AB both yield a chordal graph (a clique in the second case). However, two steps are required with addition/identification, as adding any one of the four non-edges does not yield a chordal graph.

Comment: Nice. I think the reason I missed this is I was only looking at planar graphs.

Comment: If you delete an edge from the clique between a neighbour of A and one of B, it becomes planar and still works the same. This graph is the complement of a path of length 5.

Answer (score 0):

The above example can be generalised to a class of graphs with an infinite number of examples where addition-identification needs k steps while deletion-contraction requires only one.

Indeed, this graph is the complement of two paths of length 2, and a path of length 2 is a star with two branches. Now take the complement of two stars of any sizes. Deleting or contracting the edge connecting their centres yields a chordal graph, whereas addition method has to fill in the smaller star entirely. Since identification does that in a single step, the complement of two stars with the smaller having k branches fits the bill.