# What are some lesser studied variations of coloring in Graph Theory?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'd like to look into some areas of Graph Theory that I haven't seen before, and would love the input of anyone who finds the subject interesting. If y'all wouldn't mind sharing an application of the variation in addition to just referencing it, I would appreciate it. Cheers.

Comment: There has been little discussion of the color mauve in the literature

Comment: You may find the [Dynamic Survey of Graph Labeling](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS6) interesting.

Comment: @Will, perhaps you missed this: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/580291.Mauve

Comment: You could try your hand at answering this question of mine, drewzing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801643/deletion-contraction-versus-addition-identification I recently reposted it to MathOverflow, to no avail.

Comment: @AustinMohr, thank you very much for sending this my way! This is a lot of content for me to dive into and it will definitely keep me busy for a while.

Comment: @drewzing If your goal is to work on something new, I'd recommend the following approach: Skim the text for an interesting labelling problem, then try to establish bounds for your favorite family of graphs. It gives you something concrete to work on instead of starting with difficult, general statements.