# How to create a chromatic polynomial of a specific graph?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I need to create a chromatic polynomial of a graph (can't embeed due to low rep):
https://ibb.co/9vZWPmL
Acording to MAXIMA it's: 
$$
k^6-9k^5+34k^4-65k^3+61k^2-22k
$$
But trying to touch it with any method suggested on the Internet just seems to lend me something else or quickly devolve into multitudes of sub-graphs.

Even if the answer is simpler than I think I would be thankfull for some step by step explanation.

Comment: The standard way to do these is to use the "deletion-contraction" formula, which indeed expresses the answer in terms of the chromatic polynomials of two simpler graphs. Then it may be necessary to apply the formula again to one or both of the simpler graphs, to get even simpler graphs. The goal is to get graphs that are simple enough that a "follow-your-nose" approach suffices for finding their chromatic polynomials, and then you work your way back up through the chain of graphs until you get back to the one you started with. Continued.

Comment: Maybe with that in mind, you can look at the methods you have found, and understand what they are doing. Or look at some of the questions about chromatic polynomials that have been asked & answered on this website. Look at all the questions listed under Related on this page.

Comment: It ended up being mostly an issue with how flexible the actuall solution can be when compared to what I expected (since it involved both adding-contraction and some of the basic formulas). But long story short, you are right.

Comment: Good. Now you can write it up, and post it as an answer.

Comment: You can label the vertices and list the edges as pairs of vertices and place that in the question. No need to supply a drawing of the graph How did you represent the graph in MAXIMA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for an answer for this (or similar) question - it ended up being a "addition - contraction" issue.

Steps:

1. Create first subgraf by adding edge between verticles 3 and 4
   (turning [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,6]]
   into [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,6]]).
2. Create second subgraf by contracting verticles 3 and 4 (turning [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,5],[3,6],[4,5],[4,6]] into [[1,2],[1,34],[2,34],[34,5],[34,6]]).
3. Create polynomials for both subgrafs (first being a full graph and two partial traingles; second being a triangle and two "lines" -
   bringing both down to polynomials that can be found on the web).
4. Add both polynomials.

Comment: The graph has several $4$-cycles without chords: $2354$, $2364$, and $3546$. You can't break up all three by a single deletion-contraction operation, if you go that way you have to do it twice, but you can break up all the $4$-cycles by adding the $34$ edge, so you only need one application of addition-contraction. Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801643/deletion-contraction-versus-addition-identification